# Hibernate sess.flush() hangs

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a method loading up a persistent object and then have it updated. When I use flush(), the process hangs with no errors. Any idea?

Code:

```
    public Task changeStatus(Long taskNo, String status) {
    Session sess = HibernateUtil
            .getSessionFactory()
            .openSession();
    Task task = (Task) sess.load(Task.class, taskNo);
    
    task.setStatus(status);
    
    sess.flush();
    return task;
}
```

The log shows this:

> INFO: 09:33:05,329 DEBUG Printer:83 - listing entities:
>
> INFO: 09:33:05,329 DEBUG Printer:90 - models.Task{userByAssignedToCheck=null, client=models.Client#1, status=Withdrawn, datasets=, urgent=false, taskLogs=, userByCheckedBy=null, dateReceived=29 August 2013, dateCompleted=null, fee=null, onTime=false, userByOriginatorId=models.User#1, taskCat=null, userByAssignedToWork=null, source=null, originatorOld=null, description=null, userByCompletedBy=null, method=null, taskNo=11492, dueDate=null, requestVia=null, comments=}
>
> INFO: 09:33:05,329 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:366 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
>
> INFO: 09:33:05,329 DEBUG SQL:401 - /* update models.Task */ update DBAKZHU0.INFO_TASK set CLIENTNO=?, ASSIGNEDTOCHECK=?, TASKTYPENO=?, COMPLETEDBY=?, CHECKEDBY=?, ORIGINATORID=?, SOURCENO=?, ASSIGNEDTOWORK=?, METHOD=?, REQUESTVIA=?, DATERECEIVED=?, DATECOMPLETED=?, DUEDATE=?, STATUS=?, ORIGINATOROLD=?, ONTIME=?, URGENT=?, FEE=?, DESCRIPTION=? where TASKNO=?
>
> INFO: Hibernate: /* update models.Task */ update DBAKZHU0.INFO_TASK set CLIENTNO=?, ASSIGNEDTOCHECK=?, TASKTYPENO=?, COMPLETEDBY=?, CHECKEDBY=?, ORIGINATORID=?, SOURCENO=?, ASSIGNEDTOWORK=?, METHOD=?, REQUESTVIA=?, DATERECEIVED=?, DATECOMPLETED=?, DUEDATE=?, STATUS=?, ORIGINATOROLD=?, ONTIME=?, URGENT=?, FEE=?, DESCRIPTION=? where TASKNO=?

Comment: Yeah, I have some ideas. Are you aware that when you execute commands in hibernate, they don't straight go to the DB, right? When you flush, it is the same as executing all commands at once. So the problem problem is showing up here, but it may be caused by an entirely different class/code. First off, try to isolate the smallest possible sequence of commands that cause the error. Where do you open the session? Add a flush after each single command. The error should popup where it actually happens. Also, when it hangs, can you debug the database? Check if there are deadlocks? What DB is it?

Comment: Hi, my first reaction is the deadlock however I dont have admin priviledge on the database so I couldnt see the locks. The above codes are the only Hibernate calls made within that request. the session is opened by the sessionFactory with no special mechanics.

Comment: I came here having the same issue. Turned out I had uncomitted changes in my SQL Developer causing the hang....  Once I committed, all worked as expected.

Comment: Your comment deserves to be an answer @Lawrence :)